# How to set a constraint for a non-linear least squares problem

Tags: optimization, least-squares, matlab, scipy, constraint

I am trying to fit some data where the cost function is $ax^2 + bx + c$ and I need to have $a+b+c = 1$. How do I set such a constraint in MATLAB or Python?

Answer (score 1):

An equality constraint is simple to incorporate. Express $c$ as $1-a-b$ and substitute to obtain $ax^2+bx+(1-a-b)$ which you can then optimize without constraints.

Comment: Asking for code is generally off topic. I would have included it nevertheless if only I were familiar with Matlab or Python, but I am not.